# why would some features of stackoverflow be unavailable for me at home but available at work

Tags: support, cdn

I'm suddenly having difficulty getting to Stackoverflow from home. The pages are slow to load and displaying without styling. But other sites seem to be working fine.

Checking network tools I see this:

cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow
service unavailable

But when I log into my work PC via GoToMyPC, there are no such problems with SO. SO is working fine from there.  Are there multiple replicated nodes of SO, so that some may be experiencing technical issues while others are functioning smoothly?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92452/cdn-sstatic-net-is-slowing-down-initial-page-loads and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120191/waiting-for-cdn-sstatic-net-waits-too-much both with official answers. :)

Answer (score 6):

This might have something to do with it:

[We are looking into the CDN issues now, hang tight.](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/510149572925345792)

and

[We are working with CloudFlare on tracking down the CDN root cause - please let us know your location if you're still seeing issues.](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/510151474421444608)

and

[We're tracking down the cause of 503's on the CDN. Those with issues please tweet us the colo= line of this page: http://cdn.sstatic.net/cdn-cgi/trace](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/510152776417304576)

follow the drama unfold [here](https://twitter.com/StackStatus).

From [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100) the following domains need to be in working order:

- sstatic.net (and its subdomains) for Stack Exchange JavaScript and CSS static resources
- googleapis.com for jQuery effects
- api.recaptcha.net for viewing CAPTCHAs
- imgur.com for viewing most images
- stackauth.com for Global Network Auto-Login.
- gravatar.com for viewing user avatars
- cdn.mathjax.org to see formulas on MathJax-enabled sites
- sockets.ny.stackexchange.com

Comment: Aha.  Weird that it was working and not working in two places very close to each other.

Comment: Rep cap here we come! ;)