# Sponsored tag images not loading

Tags: bug, status-completed, sponsored-tags, cdn

The sponsored tag images are not loading for me:

[image: sponsored tag images]

The request gets a 500 error after 21 seconds using cdn.sstatic.net:

[image: cdn - 500 error after 21 seconds]

Location: London, England.

Comment: No repro here in Geneva, Switzerland.

Comment: Reproduced specifically for android here in the US (East coast).  Other sponsored tags seem to load ok (like Adobe, for instance).  It seems to be tied to this image: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/hosted/tKsDb.png

Comment: @jadarnel27 - For me it looks like _all_ sponsored tags.

Comment: Weird.  I can get this one: http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-adobe.png.  But not the android one.

Comment: Why are your errors pointing at the load time? Why not point at the "500 Internal Server Error" part? P.S. All images are loading fine for me (US Central).

Comment: I noticed these were being slow loading, but they did load eventually for me.

Comment: @animuson - I originally noted the load times. Only when posting the image did I notice the 500 errors.

Comment: Reproduced 500 in the Netherlands (eg: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/hosted/dmHl0.png (Chrome 18 & Firefox 11).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128744/openid-logos-missing-on-login-failed-page reports similar issues observed from NZ, thanks Rob W for pointing this question out.

Comment: Is this still occurring? See [balpha's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100103/3) for additional things to check when CDN woes occur.

Comment: @JarrodDixon - Looks like it got sorted out by itself.