# OpenID logos missing on "login failed" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, login

I just tried to log in for the first time, and for whatever reason was shown this:

[image: UI at users/authenticate on failed openid request]

The default login buttons (StackExchange, Google, Yahoo etc) are missing. I think this may have happened due to a failure authenticating with MyOpenID (third attempt was the trick).

For users who've failed auth, I would have thought that the buttons should be displayed again. "OK, I'll try logging in via FOO Network."

Comment: http://cl.ly/2F3T2F1z1Q3P000t0H1E/o - uncropped screenshot

Comment: Bug seems to be related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128740/sponsored-tag-images-not-loading (CDN seems to experience issues).

Comment: Are you still seeing missing images on the login page?  If so, which [CDN node](http://debug-02.netdna-cdn.com/) are you hitting?

Comment: @Jarrod Dixon - Sorry, I can't reproduce the issue because I need to have the OpenID login mysteriously fail to see that screen. Note the "Unable to log in with your OpenID provider" warning at top. I saw this after logging in via delegated openid, auth with MyOpenID worked OK, but on redirection to Stackexchange it didn't auth me as usual.

Comment: I can repro this now - we'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix will be pushed out in the next build, > rev 2012.4.11.2198.