# android image missing

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sponsored tag images not loading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128740/sponsored-tag-images-not-loading)

I have observed that image is missing for android button. Not sure whether it is case for me only or for everyone.

Here is screenshot.[image]